# Android PreferenceScreen sits on top of Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

Below is the screenshot of how the preference screen looks like :

[image: screenshot showing problem]

I am also including the layout and java code :

#### layout/toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/primary_dark"
android:elevation="0dp"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

#### layout/activity_settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### xml/fragment_settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Notifications">
        <SwitchPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="currencyNotificationOnOff"
            android:title="@string/notification_enable" />

        <com.adwitiya.currencyplus.view.TimePickerDialog
            android:defaultValue="08:00"
            android:dependency="currencyNotificationOnOff"
            android:key="scheduleNotificationTime"
            android:showDefault="true"
            android:title="Notification Time" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="">
        <Preference
            android:key="about"
            android:title="@string/about" />
        <Preference
            android:key="disclaimer"
            android:title="@string/disclaimer" />
        <Preference
            android:key="help"
            android:title="@string/help" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="General">
        <Preference
            android:key="spreadWord"
            android:title="@string/prefs_spread_word" />
        <Preference
            android:key="rateUs"
            android:title="@string/rate_us" />
        <Preference
            android:key="feedback"
            android:title="@string/feedback" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

#### SettingsActivity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
        TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.fragment_settings, false);
    }
}
```

#### SettingsFragment.java

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_settings);

        handleSettingsOptions();
    }
    ....
}
```

I am unable to keep the toolbar at the top and the preference screen elements below it. When the options are scrolled, it moves on top of the toolbar.

I am using a single preference screen and the each preference opens a webview.

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still working on this issue.. I will post something once I am able to fix it.

Comment: What I found is that the background of the PreferenceScreen is behind the toolbar, whereas the *content* of the PreferenceScreen is rendered above the toolbar! Absolutely baffling. Haven't found a good solution yet (apart from the workaround below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the issue. The changes that I have made are as follows :

1. Removed the toolbar from 'activity_settings.xml'
2. Removed the toolbar related code from 'SettingsActivity.java'
3. In 'AndroidManifest.xml', to the activity I added 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar' theme (change according to your requirement).

Comment: I ran into the same issue after changing from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `NoActionBar` and adding the appropriate layouts (CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout, etc).

I changed the theme so that I could match the theme of the Preferences activity to the theme of my main activity. This is 'required' because the title text of the default toolbar (the one from DarkActionBar theme) is too small compared to most other Material design apps. Additionally, the toolbar needs to move away when scrolling down.

I haven't found the right answer to this problem yet.

Comment: What about a menu option to reset all settings? Without Toolbar you can't do it.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this work to other that the accepted answer not work for you.

In **Layout/activity_setting.xml** change the code so looks like this below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<!-- added code -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In **SettingsActivity.java**, replace this code

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
```

With this one

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following has worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This way you can still use your regular Toolbar and its theme will stay intact.